# R package: how to make my package loading other package when I library my package

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I have made my own package called "test" and I install it. However, there exist some problem.

For example, in my .R file, I use function "rowQuantiles" from other package called "matrixStats".

And I already add

```
import(matrixStats)
```

to namespace file

and add

```
Imports:matrixStats (>= 0.57.0)
```

to description file.

However, whenever I library my own pakcage

```
library(test)
```

The following error always comes out

```
could not find function "rowQuantiles"
```

How can I make that whenever I library my own package it will load other required packages. Just like the following

```
> library(ggpubr)
Loading required package: ggplot2
```

Comment: try getting the function from the other package by using this grammar `package::method() ` to call the method into your package, it should also load all of the required dependencies for that method with it.

Comment: @sconfluentus Hi, thanks, which file  should  i put "package::method()"

Comment: I am sorry, I may not have been clear. You would replace the word `package`, with the name of the package that you will be using the function/method from and then replace `method()` with the actual function, and example:  `dplyr::select( )`  does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key to understand this is to understand the difference between *loading* a package and *attaching* a package.

Packages listed under `Imports:` are only *loaded* when your package attached, i.e. when you do `library(mypkg)`.  In contrast, packages listed under `Depends:` are loaded *and* attached.  So, if you use:

```
Depends: matrixStats
```

then all of **matrixStats** functions will be on the `search()` path when you package is attached.